# dellocating memory does it degrade the performance?

Tags: optimization, vba, language-agnostic, memory-management

This is a basic Question for all programming languages, But I am much familiar with VBA.So Im using the vba code. I got some doubt with deallocating the memory.Does the performance degarde when we erase or swap off the allocated contents ?
something like

**Method I** where we deallocate the allocated memory

```
sub my_function()
     Dim a() as string
     redim a(1 to 15)
     'some for loop  goes here aroung 50 iterations
     erase a ' Deallocate the array
     ' some piece of code goes here may be 40 lines
end sub
```

**Method II** where we dont deallocate any memory

```
sub my_function()
     Dim a() as string
     redim a(1 to 15)
     'some for loop  goes here aroung 50 iterations
     'some piece of code goes here may be 40 lines
end sub
```

**Method III** where we dellocate memory at the last statment

```
sub my_function()
     Dim a() as string
     redim a(1 to 15)
     'some for loop  goes here aroung 50 iterations
     'some piece of code goes here may be 40 lines
     erase a 'deallocate the memory
end sub
```

The question

**Method I** is erase a, Does it eat up any huge cycles ? or more bytes of ram ? or should i wait for the end of the sub routine or should I go for using erase statement

**Method II** There is no erase statement in the sub routine, the function kills the array at the end of sub routine but I dont need the array till the end of function so is this fast enough or optimized?

**Method III** At the first watch, people say its a foolish thing to dellocate at the end of the sub routine as itself kills at the end,But I am eager to know Thanks

Comment: "More lines = bad" -- I don't know where this attitude comes from. Checking string variable length as a means of checking if a string variable contains anything is a best practice since it's faster than a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will somewhat depend on the language used and how large the memory being used is.
For VBA in 99.99% of all the cases I can imagine there is no performance gain from deallocateing array memory, and its probably marginally slower. 
There are rare cases in VBA where it is worthwhile explicitly destroying objects.

For languages such as C/C++ that do not automatically handle memory deallocation it is important to explicitly program memory deallocation so that your code does not contain a memory leak.

Comment: What he said. My understanding is that (in most cases) VBA automatically deallocates memory, when variables go out of scope.

Comment: The quesion is why you have to make a variable alive till the end of function when it is of no use after the first 10 lines in a 1000 lines of code

Comment: The only reason for trying to minimise memory use is if the VBA is using so much memory that it makes the Operating system do a lot of slow paging. This is very unlikely to occur on current PCs. Erasing an array is almost certainly slower than leaving it to VBA to clean it up, (although its unlikely that you will notice the additional microseconds the Erase will take)